# WPF GridView: The property 'Header' is set more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm getting this compiler error but I don't think I am specifying the header twice.

Here's the code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Margin" Width="180" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Margin">
    <Binding Path="Margin" Converter="{StaticResource currencyStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#0.00"></Binding>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I am trying to bind to the column value, not the column header. This is always 'Margin'.

I have tried several variations, like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Margin">
    <Binding Path="Margin" Converter="{StaticResource currencyStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#0.00"></Binding>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Margin"></GridViewColumnHeader>
</GridViewColumn>
```

but all yield the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

M

Comment: Take this out and test   ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Margin"  I bet it is setting a header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Margin" 
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Margin, Converter={StaticResource currencyStringConverter} , ConverterParameter='#0.00'}" 
ctrls:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Margin"/>
```

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[LocalizabilityAttribute(LocalizationCategory.None, Readability = Readability.Unreadable)]
[ContentPropertyAttribute("Header")]
[StyleTypedPropertyAttribute(Property = "HeaderContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(GridViewColumnHeader))]
public class GridViewColumn : DependencyObject, 
    INotifyPropertyChanged
```

`Content` property of this object is Header so you can't do this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Margin" ...>
    <Binding ...
</GridViewColumn>
```

because in this case you set header twice.

Comment: Thanks kmatyaszek that's perfect. You can see that I haven't done WPF for a while...